# Perl multiple line matching while reading from file, line by line

Tags: regex, perl, lines

Lets say I open a file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, "8882099";
while ($line = <FILE>) {
  if ($line =~ /accepted by(.*?)\./s) {
    print "accepted by: $1";
  }
}
```

the problem is the regex is working, but since the file is read line by line, how should I go about matching this string which continues on to a new line?

Thank you

Comment: Captain: Read more lines. You cannot match data you have not read.

Comment: so you want to match up through the next `.` even across lines?

Comment: exactly, that's what i want to do

Answer (score 4):

It's often simplest just to read the entire file at once.

```
my $file;
{
   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i figured it would be something like this. i'll look into this, cause the file could reach 50-100mb.

Comment: @Sla That's about $0.05 USD in RAM.

Comment: I agree with jordanm, 100mb isn't a problem, its when you get file that are comparable to much larger than your ram that you run into issues.

Comment: It's also when you split the files into tons of small strings that you get into problems (because of the overhead of each scalar and of all the arrays holding them).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every program. That way simple mistakes you would otherwise overlook will be pointed out to you.

Secondly, you should use lexical file names, the *three-parameter form* of `open`, and always check the status of every `open` call.

To solve you problem, you should simply look for a line that contains the prefix `accepted by`, and then append lines to the string you have found until you see the complete string match. It is also better to use an explicit `[^.]+` than the non-greedy `.*?` to avoid backtracking.

Note that you should reinstate the file open that I have commented out, and remove the assignment to `$file`, as I have written the program this way for test purposes.

This solution will have a problem if `accepted by` is split over multiple lines. If you expect this then something slightly different will have to be coded.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# open my $file, '<', '8882099' or die $!;
my $file = \*DATA;

my $line;
while ($line = <$file>) {

  if ($line =~ /accepted by/) {
    $line .= <$file> until $line =~ /accepted by\s*([^.]*)\./;
    print "accepted by: $1\n";
  }

}

__DATA__

    accepted by Tim.


    accepted by The
Financial
Director.
Today
```

**output**

```
accepted by: Tim
accepted by: The
Financial
Director
```